# Programmatically open new CMD and enter code *but not run it*?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, shell-script, windows-terminal

Is it possible in Windows to programmatically launch a new instance of CMD, Terminal, or PS (doesn't matter which) and populate the input field with some arbitrary code, just like if a user was typing it, but *not automatically execute the code*?

I know it's possible to launch a CMD (or any shell) instance with a given command or script to execute immediately. That's not what I'm asking. I would like the CMD window to appear, the code text to appear in the input field right after the `>`, and *that's it.* The user would still be able to edit or delete the line(s) of code before anything is executed in the shell. It would be the user's responsibility to run the code (i.e. press the `Enter` key) when they are ready.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @DavidPostill the question was "is this possible"? I never asked anyone to write the code for me. I have researched and turned up nothing, so I'm trying to determine whether it's even worth further digging

Comment: Yes, it’s possible.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses! Looks like AutoHotKey is required, which isn't terrible

Comment: "Is it possible" questions don't really fit here. Possibility is based on too many factors, many of them based on aspects of the askers self, person, and capability. Further, the majority of people who use phrases like "is it possible" actually mean "solve this problem for me" because of oblique language habits and culture, so we assume that's what is usually meant.